# Llamada a un método en Laravel mediante API

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Tengo un método en lumen que se encarga de recibir un array de archivos , hacer un bucle e insertarlos en BD, este método me funciona correctamente si hago la prueba con postman.

Luego intento hacer la llamada desde un componente de Vue2 y lo hago de esta forma:

```
<template>
  <div class="example-drag">
    <div class="upload">
      <ul v-if="files.length">
        <li v-for="(file, index) in files" :key="file.id">
          <span>{{file.name}}</span> -
           <span>{{file.size}}</span> -
          <span v-if="file.error">{{file.error}}</span>
          <span v-else-if="file.success">success</span>
          <span v-else-if="file.active">active</span>
          <span v-else></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul v-else>
        <td colspan="7">
          <div class="text-center p-5">
            <h4>Drop files anywhere to upload<br/>or</h4>
            <label for="file" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Seleccionar archivos</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </ul>

      <div v-show="$refs.upload && $refs.upload.dropActive" class="drop-active">
            <h3>Drop files to upload</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="example-btn">
        <file-upload
          class="btn btn-primary"
          post-action="http://localhost:8000/api/v1/car/upload"
          :multiple="true"
          :drop="true"
          :drop-directory="true"
          v-model="files"
          ref="upload">
          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
          Seleccionar archivos
        </file-upload>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" v-if="!$refs.upload || !$refs.upload.active" @click.prevent="$refs.upload.active = true">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Empezar la subida de archivos
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"  v-else @click.prevent="$refs.upload.active = false">
          <i class="fa fa-stop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Parar subida de archivos
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FileUpload from 'vue-upload-component'
export default {
  components: {
    FileUpload,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      files: [],
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Si miro en la respuesta del google chrome veo lo siguiente , lo veo todo correcto pero realmente no me accede bien al método de la api

[image]

Comment: ¿Qué significa "no accede bien al método de la API"? No es claro tu problema.

Comment: Disculpar , lo aclaro. Como podeis ver en el request payload veo el archivo que envio por post , sin embargo en el método de la API no recibo ese parametro y no se bien bien como "debugar" esto